# How to cache a server call and test for cache expiration prior to calling for new data?

Tags: php, caching

I'm using this script to retrieve a list of Google web fonts. How can I cache the results and use that to determine whether to load from cache or server call?

```
$googleFontsArray = array();
$googleFontsArrayContents = file_get_contents('http://phat-reaction.com/googlefonts.php?format=php');
$googleFontsArrayContentsArr = unserialize($googleFontsArrayContents);

foreach($googleFontsArrayContentsArr as $font)
{
    $googleFontsArray[$font['font-name']] = $font['font-name'];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a local copy of the serialized data and only update the file every hour:

```
$cache_file = 'font_cache';

$update_cache = false;
$source = $cache_file;
if(!file_exists($cache_file) || time() - filemtime($cache_file) >= 3600) // Cache for an hour
{
     $source = 'http://phat-reaction.com/googlefonts.php?format=php';
     $update_cache = true;
}

$googleFontsArray = array();
$googleFontsArrayContents = file_get_contents($source);
$googleFontsArrayContentsArr = unserialize($googleFontsArrayContents);

foreach($googleFontsArrayContentsArr as $font)
{
    $googleFontsArray[$font['font-name']] = $font['font-name'];
}

if($update_cache)
{
    file_put_contents($cache_file, $googleFontsArrayContents);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would want to make a server call whenever the google web fonts file changes. This isn't really possible in one script.  Ideally you would have another script that only queries and caches the font list, and the code you listed here will always use the cached value.