# Strange Code in Blob Fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been killing myself with this database trying to extract the right data so I hope you can help me!

After trying a number of SQL editors (MySQL WorkBench, Sequel Pro and RazorSQL and PHPMyAdmin) I haven't been able to figure out how to decode this strange output of a BLOB column:

a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"src";s:30:"joburg-vic-falls-11-days-0.jpg";s:3:"alt";s:0:"";s:4:"desc";s:0:"";}}

The above is for an image as you can perhaps see by the slug.jpg. Can any of you tell me what code this is so I can decode it somewhere to make it useful?

I am moving a database from Contao to WP and having to manually piece it together. Decoding this will get me a lot further along. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: that's a php serialized array. http://php.net/serialize, or if not php, at least something similar.

Comment: That's great thank you @MarcB . I take it I can "unserialize" it then?

Comment: yes. there's `unserialize()`. but the format's simple enough. `a:1` - array with 1 element, `i:0` integer with `0` value, `s:3`, string with 3 chars, etc...

Comment: Thanks to @MarkB's comment I've managed to find this answered question to help me fix my insane data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547009/how-to-deserialize-this-string-into-a-php-array-of-key-value-pairs

I also found this link where you can unserialize data like this online: http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/

I'll probably try to write this function into bit of a script I can run on entire columns of my database...

Comment: Yeah I see that. I need the data in the array's though so i'll need to unserialize and then use the items in the array to generate html or text