# regex for a doctrine data type string

Tags: php, arrays, doctrine-orm, preg-split

I have a look up table & in it there is the data type string array...

`a:2:{i:0;s:4:"Blah";i:1;s:7:"Testing";}`

I'm needing to loop through this so I am trying to create an array like so

`array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Blah"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Testing"
}`

I have attempted using `preg_split` and `explode` however I don't think `explode` will do what I need. I cannot figure out the correct regex to get the output I'm looking for.

I've tried: `$array = preg_split('/[" "]/', $str["lookuptable"]);`

`$array = preg_split('/[: "]/', $str["lookuptable"]);`

and a few other variations but none have worked.

Comment: simply use `unserialize($string)`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the User was trying to use a regular expression to unserialize data, but in comments somebody pointed out that the unserialize() function can handle that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deserialize this string into a PHP array of key => value pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547009/how-to-deserialize-this-string-into-a-php-array-of-key-value-pairs)